# Cross Origin issue with loading fonts and SVG in local file

Tags: html, fonts, cors

I'm executing a HTML file using file protocol in the browser like below:

```
view-source:file:///var/www/html/project/storage/temp/screengrab/designer-1477570109.html
```

It loads the css files perfectly but not the assets required by the CSS like font ttf or woff files, SVG gradients etc.

I see a Cross Origin issue in the console but I've set the cross origin header in my main serving PHP file like below:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I'm running PHP's built in web server that runs on `http://localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform XHR request for resources loaded from `file:///` because pages from `file:///` *have no origin at all*, they run as pages in isolation and have no network capabilities beyond basic network operations that run as part of HTML elements (like `<link href="..."> or``) whatsoever. For very obvious security reasons too: if files on your disk were allowed to resolve arbitrary XHR requests beyond what the HTML spec defines as being standard DOM operations, then they could access other files in the directory they were in with a simple relative URL.

If you want to test from `file:///`, the only workable way forward is to stop using `file:///` and instead access your file through a localhost URL by running either a full-fledged web server for the dir your file is in, or do what most people do and run a one-liner CLI server only for as long as you need to test your single file. Python and PHP have CLI options for this built in; if you're a JS developer using Node you can install `live-server` or `http-server` or something, etc.

If you're trying to work with HTML/CSS/JS/etc, then really you have no business with `file:///`; it's purely for explicitly loading a page on your disk in isolation. Basically: if you want to do more than just load a page and then doing nothing with it, use `http://`.